# IE8 Object Expected error when object contains null value

Tags: javascript, json, object, internet-explorer-8

I'm using a small poly fill in order to make Object.key availible for IE8.  Everything seems to be working fine when my object contains all values.  However when I have null values in the object I get an error about Object Expected.  I'm not sure why having a null would matter.  My code is as follows:

```
  var data = [{
     x: Date.UTC(2014, 8, 1),
     y: 730,
     pf: ["001", "002"],
     nf: ["001", "002"],
     t: ["001", "002"],
     im:["001"]
  }, {
     x: Date.UTC(2014, 9, 1),
     y: 742,
     pf: ["001", "002"],
     nf: ["001", "002"],
     t: ["001", "002"],
     im:["001"]
  }, {
     x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 1),
     y: 746,
     pf: ["001", "002"],
     nf: ["001", "002"],
     t: ["001", "002"],
     im:["001"]
  }, {
     x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1),
     y: null
  }, {
     x: Date.UTC(2015, 0, 1),
     y: 737,
     pf: ["001", "002"],
     nf: ["001", "002"],
     t: ["001", "002"],
     im:["001"]
  }, {
     x: Date.UTC(2015, 1, 1),
     y: 751,
     pf: ["001", "002"],
     nf: ["001", "002"],
     t: ["001", "002"],
     im:["001"]
  }, {
     x: Date.UTC(2015, 2, 1),
     y: 765,
     pf: ["001", "002"],
     nf: ["001", "002"],
     t: ["001", "002"],
     im:["001"]
  }, {
     x: Date.UTC(2015, 3, 1),
     y: 766,
     pf: ["001", "002"],
     nf: ["001", "002"],
     t: ["001", "002"],
     im:["001"]
  }, {
     x: Date.UTC(2015, 4, 1),
     y: 757,
     pf: ["001", "002"],
     nf: ["001", "002"],
     t: ["001", "002"],
     im:["001"]
  }, {
     x: Date.UTC(2015, 5, 1),
     y: 750,
     pf: ["001", "002"],
     nf: ["001", "002"],
     t: ["001", "002"],
     im:["001"]
  }, {
     x: Date.UTC(2015, 6, 1),
     y: 748,
     pf: ["001", "002"],
     nf: ["001", "002"],
     t: ["001", "002"],
     im:["001"]
  }, {
     x: Date.UTC(2015, 7, 1),
     y: 723,
     pf: ["001", "003"],
     nf: ["001", "002"],
     t: ["001", "002"],
     im:["001"]
  }]


  var pfMap = {
     "001": {
        "sd": "HI",
        "ld": "By"
     },
     "002": {
        "sd": "HI",
        "ld": "By"
     }
  }

  var nfMap = {
     "001": {
        "sd": "HI",
        "ld": "By"
     }
  }

  var tMap = {
     "001": "Hi",
     "002": "by"
  }

  var imMap={
      "001":"HI"
  }

  // Shim added to aid in IE8

  if (!Object.keys) {
    Object.keys = (function() {
      'use strict';
      var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
          hasDontEnumBug = !({ toString: null }).propertyIsEnumerable('toString'),
          dontEnums = [
            'toString',
            'toLocaleString',
            'valueOf',
            'hasOwnProperty',
            'isPrototypeOf',
            'propertyIsEnumerable',
            'constructor'
          ],
          dontEnumsLength = dontEnums.length;

      return function(obj) {
        if (typeof obj !== 'object' && (typeof obj !== 'function' || obj === null)) {
          throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
        }

        var result = [], prop, i;

        for (prop in obj) {
          if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
            result.push(prop);
          }
        }

        if (hasDontEnumBug) {
          for (i = 0; i < dontEnumsLength; i++) {
            if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, dontEnums[i])) {
              result.push(dontEnums[i]);
            }
          }
        }
        return result;
      };
    }());
  }

  //recursion

  function traverseData(data, elementName) {
     var keys = Object.keys(data);
     for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(data[keys[i]]) == "[object Object]" || Object.prototype.toString.call(data[keys[i]]) == "[object Array]") {
           traverseData(data[keys[i]], keys[i]);
        } else {
           if (elementName != null && window[elementName + "Map"]) {
              data[keys[i]] = window[elementName + "Map"][data[keys[i]]];
           }

        }

     }

   }

 traverseData(data, "data");
 var end = data;
```

As you can see its a simple recursion I'm building to create a new object for charting.  If you notice on the data object the 4th entry has its y value set to null.  If I fill this in with a number everything works as expected.  However if it is left as null i get the error.  Any idea why?

EDIT:  The line in question where the error is throw in within the polyfill.  I have it commented in the block blow

```
        if (hasDontEnumBug) {
          for (i = 0; i < dontEnumsLength; i++) {
            if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, dontEnums[i])) { //  Throws error here
              result.push(dontEnums[i]);
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Which line throws that error?

Comment: Line within the polyfill if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, dontEnums[i])) {

Comment: @Oriol Edited the post to show exactly where in the code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a problem with the logic used to detect `null` values:

```
if (typeof obj !== 'object' && (typeof obj !== 'function' || obj === null)) {
  throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
}
```

If `obj` is `null`, then `typeof obj` will be `"object"`.

Try this instead:

```
if (typeof obj !== 'object' && typeof obj !== 'function' || obj === null)
```

Now, you will get your custom `Object.keys called on non-object` error.

This `null` is due to

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(data[keys[i]]) == "[object Object]"
```

According to ECMAScript 5, `Object.prototype.toString.call(null)` must return `"[object Null]"`. But on old browsers, it may produce `"[object Object]"` instead.

Instead, you could use

```
if(typeof data[keys[i]]=== 'object' && data[keys[i]])
```

Comment: Exceptional work!  The funny thing is that this polyfill comes straight from Mozzilla's developer network.  Surprised I haven't seen this issue come up before.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Darn.  I spoke too soon.  It stopped the error, but now the recursion doest actually work to map the keys.  I get an object with no mappings  :(

Comment: I must be confused about the section where you say I could instead use `if(typeof obj === 'object' && obj)`.  What is this actually replacing?  Maybe the issue is with how I coded it.

Comment: @Mr.BigglesWorth That replaces the `if` inside the loop in `traverseData`. [Full code](http://jsfiddle.net/tjhk5goe/).

Comment: Yep that's what I thought.  Each I'm im getting the object back, but with none of the mappings there.  Its just showing me the key.

Comment: Tested with your code and ran console.log(end).  The output shows `nf: Array[2]0: "001"1: "002"` but it should be `nf: Array[2]0: Object ld: "HI" sd: "By"`

Comment: @Mr.BigglesWorth Oh, true, I used `obj` instead of `data[keys[i]]`. Now it really works. [Full code](http://jsfiddle.net/tjhk5goe/1/).

Comment: I should have known better and check which object it was referencing.  Thanks again for the help!